# Issue of imaginary bounding box near coordinates for model when viewing results in Paraview for Computational Fluid Dynamics

Tags: paraview, openfoam

When I try to upload the controlDict folder into Paraview, it is inconsistent in terms of display. At times, like the picture shown below, I can only view the image of the model at that particular size and if I try to drag it out, there seems to be an imaginary bounding box around it then prevents me from viewing the model. I am currently using WSL to learn how to use openFOAM and this is a tutorial that I followed along regarding flow in an elbow. I’d like help regarding this matter.

I was following through a tutorial online and I expected to see the model fill the screen but to my surprise, there was an imaginary bounding box that limited my ability to render it as s[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDGr8.png)een from the screenshots below.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSTlj.png)

Comment: Where does C++ come into picture here?

Comment: ParaView is not tested under WSL. Prefer using the binaries for the native OS (i.e. Windows in your case)